# Flash plays on old style profile and on feed, but not on the new profile (timeline)

Tags: flash, facebook-graph-api

I am using FB.api('/userid/feed', 'post', ....) to let a user post SWF to his own and a friend's wall. The SWF plays fine on his profile (irrespective of the fact whether he has the new timeline profile or not) and but for friends, the SWF plays only on the wall of friends who have the not switched to the timeline.

For users with new profile, clicking the play button below the thumbnail gives an error - "There was a problem with the parameters of the request. Body of an error/warning message. Title is: Invalid Request"

Any ideas?